# Login to facebook with android, phonegap, childBrowser

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I managed to log into Facebook with childBrowser plugin without any problems:

```
function deviceStart() {

   FB.init({ appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", nativeInterface: PG.FB });

};

function onPubFacebookBtn(){ // I call this from a button
var my_client_id  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
my_redirect_uri   = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
my_type           = "user_agent",
my_display        = "touch"

var authorize_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?";
authorize_url += "client_id="+my_client_id;
authorize_url += "&redirect_uri="+my_redirect_uri;
authorize_url += "&display="+my_display;
authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream,user_photos,email,user_online_presence,offline_access"

window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = facebookLocChanged;
window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = closed;
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(authorize_url);

}

function facebookLocChanged(loc){

if (/login_success/.test(loc)) { 
   var fbCode = loc.match(/code=(.*)$/)[1]

   localStorage.setItem('pg_fb_session', JSON.stringify(fbCode));

   FB.Auth.setSession(fbCode, 'connected');
   window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
}}
```

When I test if the app is logged in with

```
function getLoginStatus() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
 if (response.session) {
     alert('logged in');
 } else {
   alert('not logged in');
}
});
}
```

it returns "loged in", but when I try to get user ID i get an error saying I need an active access token:

```
function me() {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    if (response.error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
     } else {
         var data = document.getElementById('data');
          response.data.forEach(function(item) {
           var d = document.createElement('div');
           d.innerHTML = item.name;
           data.appendChild(d);
       });
       }
});
}
```

This is a mixture of 2 solutions for loging into facebook of which none works.
Help!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following code to get the Facebook user's name, please try once.

```
params='access_token='+accessToken;
            $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me",params, 
            function(response){
                fbUesrName=response.name;
                },"json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an [application on Facebook](http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-app-id/) to generate access token, then you can get the ID, but it would be in the encrypted form.